# Dynamically updating a single modal with php/jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

So I have a table of results from an sql query and I wanted to make all rows have a link that pulls up a modal with additional information based on the id of the row (which it receives from the primary key of the query). I'm having multiple issues with making this work.

1: The modal fails to load when I echo the html. It does not turn the background grey nor does it load the actual modal. I tested this outside of the echo in regular html on the page and it is also failing to load. This boggles my mind seeing as it is directly copied and pasted from a page I have where it does load. (with a different id for the modal and a href="")

2: I have the query in a separate .php file and my jquery does not appear to be posting the ID to this query.

Heres my html/php on the results page:

```
    <div class="container-fluid">                           <!-- Table goes here: May require a neg margin to fit on page w/o scroll -->
    <?php
    $style = "style='text-align:right;'";
    // Display search result
         if (!$count == 0) {
                echo "<h3>Search: \"$num $name $state $medicarelos $medicaidlos $totlos\" returned $count results</h3>";
                ?>

                <table id="resultTable" class="tablesorter">
                <thead> 
                <tr>
                <th>Provider Number</th>
                <th>Hospital Name</th>
        <th>Provider State</th>
                <th>Medicare Length of Stay</th>
                <th>Medicaid Length of Stay</th>
                <th>Overall Length of Stay</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
        <tbody>
                <?php

            while ($results = $query->fetch()) {
                $id = $results['id'];
                echo "<tr>";            
                echo "<td>".$results['provnum'];
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td><a id='$id' data-toggle='modal' href='#provmodal' class='push'>".$results['hospname'];
                echo "</a>";
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td>".$results['state'];
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td $style>".$results['medicarelos'];
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td $style>".$results['medicaidlos'];
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td $style>".$results['overalllos'];
                echo "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                }
                ?>
                </tbody>
                </table>

                <?php       
        } else {
            echo 'Nothing found';
        }
        exit();
        ?>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal HTML -->
    <div id="provmodal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Additional Information</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p><?php echo $modalresults['id'];?></p> <!-- Relaying the ID here to test if the script is working -->
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- END MODAL HTML -->
```

Heres my java for sending the rowID to the separate query:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

    $(function(){

    $('.push').click(function(){
      var ele_id = $(this).attr('id');

       $.ajax({
          type : 'post',
           url : 'modalquery.php', 
          data :  'post_id='+ ele_id, 

       success : function(r)
           {
              // now you can show output in your modal 
              $('div#provmodal').modal('show');  // put your modal id 
             $('.modal-body').modal('show').html(r);
           }
         });


                });

        });
    });
</script>
```

and lastly here is my php on the modalquery.php page

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("link_imegme.php");
$id = $_POST['post_id'];
$modalquery = $link->prepare("SELECT * FROM imegme WHERE id = :id");
$modalquery->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$modalquery->execute();
$modalresults = $modalquery->fetch());
?>
```

If anyone can aid me with any of these problems (mainly the reason why it fails to load on the page) I could probably figure the rest out.

Here is the head of the results page incase you were thinking I failed to include the java files or maybe they are in the wrong order somehow?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/css/themes/blue/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <!-- Start Java -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#resultTable").tablesorter({widgets: ['zebra']});
});
</script>
<?php
session_start();
require_once("link_imegme.php");
?>
<title>HDS: Medicare Disproportionate Share</title>
</head>
```

I appreciate any insight on this. Thank you

:EDIT: Ok so the issue with the modal displaying was that my php script was exiting outside of the } else { statement. The other unsolved issue as of yet is that my modal will display but $modalresults['id']; does  not bring up anything inside the modal.

Comment: I don't see where the modal dialogue is in your page beacuse you have not show us it. What kind of modal are you using, a jQuery dialog or what?

Comment: Scroll down in the first bit of code, its commented <!-- Modal HTML -->

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like this  will work with you

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Example of Bootstrap 3 Modals</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#myModal").modal('show');
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Confirmation</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Do you want to save changes you made to document before closing?</p>
                <p class="text-warning"><small>If you don't save, your changes will be lost.</small></p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

in the above example in order to make changes to the content of modal 
you need to select (modal-body) as this hold the content 
like this

```
$("#myModal .modal-body").html(ajax_var); //insert your data
$("#myModal").modal('show');
```

hope this help

//it might be better to use .modal('show') as a call back function after .html finish inserting data .. something like this

```
$("#myModal .modal-body").html(ajax_var).promise().done(function(){
        $("#myModal").modal('show');  
    });
```

//EDIT
**i didn't try but note that your exit(); isn't inside the Else{}..this might be your problem as it will always exit :)**